# What does (x & (x >> 1) == 0) check for?

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation

I saw this statement in a large code base, and I don't know what this check using bit manipulation is for. Is this some standard trick in bit manipulation? If so, what is it looking for?

I know that in binary, `x >> 1` shifts all the bits of `x` to the right 1 place, so anding that with `x` will guarantee the largest set bit of `x` becomes zero. But I just don't understand the purpose of this check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(x & (x >> 1)) == 0` (extra parentheses added for safety) checks if there are adjacent set bits in `x`, and evaluates to `true` if there aren't.

For example:

```
10101010 -> true
00010000 -> true
00000011 -> false
10100110 -> false
```

Comment: Ah I see. Is there an "decimal" description of what checking if there are adjacent set bits does?

Comment: @roulette01 nothing sensible that I know. Without directly talking about the binary representation you could say "checks if a number is [Fibbinary](https://oeis.org/A003714)" but that's really a property of the binary representation after all

Comment: Perhaps worth noting: a hidden land mine would be if your language/compiler uses `>>` as arithmetic right shift, you'd have to be careful, e.g. `0xaaaaaaaa` -> `d5555555`. I know Clang and GCC's C++ do this.